# While loop not breaking when condition is met

Tags: code-review

I am having trouble with the while loop not breaking,

```
While[Abs[f[a, b] - f[aold, bold]] > 10^-5,
 aold = a; bold = b;
 α = dfx[a, b];
 β = dfy[a, b];
 l[t_] = {a, b} + t*{α, β};
 h[t_] = f[l[t][[1]], l[t][[2]]];
 dh[t_] = D[h[t], t];
 tnew = t /. Solve[dh[t] == 0, t];
 a = a + tnew*α;
 b = b + tnew*β;
 count++;
 If[count == 10, Break[]];
 ]
```

When I print the output, `Abs[f[a, b] - f[aold, bold]]` is way smaller than `10^-5`, the condition should be met around `5` loops.
Can you see what is wrong with the code?

Comment: You might get better responses at SX dedicated to Mathematica.

Comment: It's hard to tell, without the rest of the code. When are you initializing `count`, for example?